# Initialize c++14 unordered_map with k buckets with key-value pair of zero

Tags: c++, c++14

I am trying to create an unordered_map with minimum number of initial buckets(k), with all key-value pairs initialized to zero. Later, it should go inside the for loop and print values.

```
int someFunction(int k){
  unordered_map<int, int> majority(k, {0,0});
}

for(auto m : majority){
  cout << m.first << " " <<  m.second << " \n";
}
```

I get the following compilation(c++ 14) error:

```
no matching function for call to ‘std::unordered_map<int, int>::unordered_map(int&, <brace-enclosed initializer list>)
```

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: what is the problem with `unordered_map<int, int> majority(k)` ?

Comment: Thanks. I tried that too. I have updated the code and now try to print values. With your proposal it does not go inside the for loop.

Comment: What does "all key-value pairs" mean? `unordered_map` contains a fixed finite number of specific key-value pairs only. If you only want to set a number of buckets for an empty container, you can use [rehash](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/rehash).

Comment: Thanks. I mean I expected k entries in the map with key-value of 0-0. It means duplicate keys(something unreasonable with maps). So, I am very inclined to think I am asking for something that is not possible to achieve...

Comment: Well, if you want multiple equivalent keys, there's `unordered_multimap`. Though it's not clear *why* you would want that. The whole question sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 1):

unordered_map represents hash data structure. By hash definition every key must be unique. So you can`t initialize majority with several zero int keys.
Instead you can use reserve function :

> void reserve ( size_type n );
>
> Request a capacity change
>
> Sets the number of buckets in the container (bucket_count) to the most
>   appropriate to contain at least n elements.
>
> If n is greater than the current bucket_count multiplied by the
>   max_load_factor, the container's bucket_count is increased and a
>   rehash is forced.
>
> If n is lower than that, the function may have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

`std::unordered_map` only supports unique keys so that constructor doesn't exist.

If you want the same key multiple times you can use a `std::unordered_multimap`. See the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multimap) for the available constructors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

int main() {

    std::unordered_multimap<int, int> map;
    const int k = 5;

    for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i)
    {
        map.emplace(0, 0);
    }

    for (auto& kv: map)
    {
        std::cout << kv.first << " " << kv.second << std::endl;
    }

}
```